# Dependency properties in wpf? Disable change notification in some cases?

Tags: c#, wpf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Setting WPF dependency property without triggering events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154184/setting-wpf-dependency-property-without-triggering-events)

this might be a total noob question, but is there a way in WPF to set a dependency property on a control but NOT fire the property changed event handler?

So, Im trying to set a dependency property "A" on a control that has some custom logic built in when "A" changes.

Now, I want to set property "A" but not fire the logic in the changed event handler...?
Thanks!

Comment: My question is why would you ever want to do that in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

you can create your own control that inherits from it. then override the event handler you want to customize and add logic to determine whether or not to cancel the event.